# linux shell script -search in directory inside files its date is today and 3 day before

Tags: linux, shell, date, grep

I have the following files:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
...
```

I want to search inside these files using `grep` but my search must be limited on files its date is today and 3 day befor 
for example if `file1.txt` is created in this `day(16/09/2017)` and `file2.txt` is created in `(14/09/2017)` then `grep` search only in this two files.

I want to do that command in shell script.

I only know how to search in files using one line command such

```
grep wordToSearch file*
```

Comment: I suggest to take a look at `man find`.

Comment: @TomFenech i try that command it not give me anything and second answer is result but i want to not define each time a date

Comment: I would recommend that you try and understand the answers proposed in the other question and adapt them to your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find -type f -mtime -3  -exec grep "wordToSearch" \{\} \;
```

Comment: I want to specified file start with fil and end with txt extension in the command.